# Format json data or generate dynamic struct

Tags: go, struct, dynamic

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name",
      "default": "Chuck"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Last name"
    },
    "telephone": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Telephone",
      "minLength": 10
    }
  }
}
```

I want to construct the data shown in the above figure and send it to the front end for rendering. It must contain the type and properties fields. The fields in properties are core data.

```
    //testMap is a map. key is variable name , value is value
    testMap := DrawValueNameFromPareSelfFile(testPath)

    marshal, _ := json.MarshalIndent(testMap, "", " ")

    res := string(marshal)
    helper.Ok(c, res)
```

```
type Resp struct {
    Code    errcode.Code `json:"code" binding:"required"`
    Message string       `json:"message" binding:"required"`
    Data    interface{}  `json:"data" binding:"required"`
}

// Ok
func Ok(c *gin.Context, data interface{}) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, Resp{
        Code: errcode.ErrNone,
        Data: data,
    })
}
```

But this is my result

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "data": "{\n  \"title\": \"Product Set\",\n  \"type\": \"object\",\n  \"properties\": {\n      \"id\": {\n        \"type\": \"number\"\n      },\n      \"name\": {\n        \"type\": \"string\"\n      },\n      \"price\": {\n        \"type\": \"number\"\n      },\n      \"dimensions\": {\n        \"type\": \"object\",\n        \"properties\": {\n          \"length\": {\n            \"type\": \"number\"\n          },\n          \"width\": {\n            \"type\": \"number\"\n          },\n          \"height\": {\n            \"type\": \"number\"\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      \"warehouseLocation\": {\n        \"type\": \"object\",\n        \"properties\": {\n          \"latitude\": {\n            \"type\": \"number\"\n          },\n          \"longitude\": {\n            \"type\": \"number\"\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n}\n"
}
```

There are line breaks and escape characters。
I tried to build structs with map, but I was annoyed by case conversion and nested structs

This is the method I currently use. However, when parsing JSON, it cannot be changed into lowercase letters. The front end needs lowercase letters

```
package main


import (
    "errors"
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)
// 构造器
type Builder struct {
    // 用于存储属性字段
    fileId []reflect.StructField
}

func NewBuilder() *Builder {
    return &Builder{}
}
// 添加字段
func (b *Builder)AddField(field string,typ reflect.Type) *Builder {
    b.fileId = append(b.fileId,reflect.StructField{Name: field,Type: typ})
    return b
}
// 根据预先添加的字段构建出结构体
func (b *Builder)Build() *Struct {
    stu := reflect.StructOf(b.fileId)
    index := make(map[string]int)
    for i := 0; i < stu.NumField(); i++ {
        index[stu.Field(i).Name] = i
    }
    return &Struct{stu,index}
}
func (b *Builder) AddString(name string) *Builder {
    return b.AddField(name, reflect.TypeOf(""))
}

func (b *Builder) AddBool(name string) *Builder {
    return b.AddField(name, reflect.TypeOf(true))
}

func (b *Builder) AddInt64(name string) *Builder {
    return b.AddField(name, reflect.TypeOf(int64(0)))
}

func (b *Builder) AddFloat64(name string) *Builder {
    return b.AddField(name, reflect.TypeOf(float64(1.2)))
}

func (b *Builder) AddStruct(name string) *Builder {
    // type T struct { a, b int }
    tmp := make(map[string]string)
    tmp["test"] = "test"
    return b.AddField(name, reflect.TypeOf(tmp))
}

// 实际生成的结构体，基类
// 结构体的类型
type Struct struct {
    typ reflect.Type
    // <fieldName : 索引> // 用于通过字段名称，从Builder的[]reflect.StructField中获取reflect.StructField
    index map[string]int
}

func (s Struct)New() *Instance {
    return &Instance{reflect.New(s.typ).Elem(),s.index}
}
// 结构体的值
type Instance struct {
    instance reflect.Value
    // <fieldName : 索引>
    index map[string]int
}
var (
    FieldNoExist error = errors.New("field no exist")
)
func (in Instance)Field(name string) (reflect.Value,error) {
    if i,ok := in.index[name];ok{
        return in.instance.Field(i),nil
    }else {
        return reflect.Value{},FieldNoExist
    }
}



func (in *Instance) SetStruct(name string, resp map[string]string) {
    if i,ok := in.index[name];ok{
        for k ,v := range resp {
            // value, _ :=v.(string)
            fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(k))
            fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(v))
            // in.instance.Field(i).SetString("test")
            in.instance.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(resp))
        }

        
    }
}


func (in *Instance) SetString(name, value string) {
    if i,ok := in.index[name];ok{
        in.instance.Field(i).SetString(value)
    }
}

func (in *Instance) SetBool(name string, value bool) {
    if i,ok := in.index[name];ok{
        in.instance.Field(i).SetBool(value)
    }
}

func (in *Instance) SetInt64(name string, value int64) {
    if i,ok := in.index[name];ok{
        in.instance.Field(i).SetInt(value)
    }
}

func (in *Instance) SetFloat64(name string, value float64) {
    if i,ok := in.index[name];ok{
        in.instance.Field(i).SetFloat(value)
    }
}
func (i *Instance) Interface() interface{} {
    return i.instance.Interface()
}

func (i *Instance) Addr() interface{} {
    return i.instance.Addr().Interface()
}



func main() {
    pe := NewBuilder().
        AddString("Name").
        AddInt64("Age").
        AddStruct("Typet").
        Build()
    p := pe.New()
    p.SetString("Name","你好")
    p.SetInt64("Age",32)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",p)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",p.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",p.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",p.Addr())
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",p.Addr())




    tmp := make(map[string]string)

    tmp["type1"] = "object1"
    tmp["type2"] = "object2"
    tmp["type3"] = "object3"


    p.SetStruct("Typet",tmp)


    fmt.Printf("%T\n",p)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",p.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",p.Interface())
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",p.Addr())
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",p.Addr())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `map` for dynamic fields.

Really dynamic data can be stored in `map[string]interface{}`

For limited number of fields, you can use strong type:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Type       string              `json:"type"`
    Properties map[string]RespProp `json:"properties"`
}

type RespProp struct {
    Type      string `json:"type"`
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    Default   string `json:"default,omitempty"`
    MinLength int    `json:"minLength,omitempty"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/W8mpg7HvCwM

Comment: I tried this method, but the problem is that I can't build the structure in advance, because the fields in properties are changed, similar to the struct RespProp you mentioned.

Comment: At present, I have found a way to build it, but there is no way to solve the problem of letter case. When parsing JSON data, it becomes lowercase. Because the front end needs lowercase letters.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can see my current practice

Comment: Reflection provides a little help here as you have to implement all `SetXXX` methods manually. You can add these methods to my `Response` structure, where every method adds an item to `Properties ` map without reflection.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help